# Showing error while writing classes in render using material framework

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm new to typescript, i couldn't able to figure it out how to give classes (Styles) in the component using typescript. Can anyone help me in solving the issue?

```
import React from "react";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

const styles = (theme: any) => ({
  root: {
    "& > *": {
      margin: theme.spacing(5),
      width: "25ch"
    }
  }
});
interface Props {}

interface State {}
class TextFields extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <form className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off">
        <Grid container direction={"column"} spacing={5}>
          <Grid item>
            <TextField label="First Name" variant="outlined" />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            <TextField label="Last Name" variant="outlined" />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            <TextField label="Address" variant="outlined" />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            <TextField label="Email" variant="outlined" />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
export default withStyles(styles)(TextFields);
```

Please help me in this query?

[Here is the sample one](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-cohen-1qv9b)

Comment: `Props` interface is empty, you must add the `classes` property to make it _visible_. Also note that using HOC is the more convoluted way to use it (consider `useStyles()` or `styled()` instead).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti - Can you explain or assist me where to align useStyles()

Comment: There are a couple of good examples in the docs: https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/